# Strict Standards: Non-static method STemplate::assign() should not be called statically

Tags: php, xampp, smarty

i Upgrade my old xampp (1.7.3) localhost server to 1.8.0 . now, not work smarty template engine (2.6.6) in my all page and i see `Strict Standards` error. what's problem? how to fix this ?

`NOTE : This Wroked Fine In Old Xampp(1.7.3).`

Section of Error :

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method STemplate::assign() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\tube\include\config.php on line 88

Strict Standards: Non-static method STemplate::create() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\tube\libraries\mysmarty.class.php on line 42

Strict Standards: Non-static method STemplate::setCompileDir() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\tube\include\config.php on line 181

Strict Standards: Non-static method STemplate::setTplDir() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\tube\include\config.php on line 182
```

My Config Line Error :

```
STemplate::assign($field, $config[$field]); // line 88
STemplate::setCompileDir($config['basedir']."/temporary"); // line 181
STemplate::setTplDir($config['basedir']."/themes"); // line 182
```

my.Smarty.class.php (error line 2)

```
function assign($var, $value) {
        global $Smarty;
        if (!isset($Smarty)) {
            STemplate::create(); // <---- line 42
        }
        $Smarty->assign($var, $value);
    }
```

Thanks For Any Help :)

Comment: function assign is not a static method but you called it as it would be a static method. Normally you call a method with $instance->assign(). So that's your issue. So you should upgrade all software and see then if you need to modify your code further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using a modern version of PHP with `strict standards`. You may be able to make the code work by making the declaration:

```
public static function assign($var, $value)
```

However judging by the other errors you'll run into many problems. You can try disabling strict standards but it'd be best to upgrade to a modern version of [`Smarty`](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: You right! but i dont have any time for change/upgrade Smarty to new ver! so i change function to public static. function `strict standards` error fixed but i see new error : `Notice: Undefined variable: ending in C:\xampp\htdocs\tube\members.php on line 214`. line 214 is : `STemplate::assign('beginning',$beginning);`

Comment: It's probably the line before, or after that, and it likely either needs an `isset` check or to be initialised prior to use.

Comment: all template code in member page :`//TEMPLATES BEGIN`
`STemplate::assign('beginning',$beginning); line 213` 
`STemplate::assign('ending',$ending); line 214`
`STemplate::assign('pagelinks',$pagelinks); line 215`
`STemplate::assign('total',$total); line 216`
`STemplate::assign('listvideos',$users); line 217`
`STemplate::display('header.tpl'); line 218`
`STemplate::display('members.tpl'); line 219`
`STemplate::display('footer.tpl'); line 220`
`//TEMPLATES END`

Comment: Ok so $ending isn't defined, that's probably a mistake in your code somewhere.. at a minimum you could try: `STemplate::assign('ending', isset($ending) ? $ending : '');`