# Non-static method utf_normalizer::nfc() should not be called statically

Tags: php, static-methods, phpbb, phpbb3, static

At the moment, I am installing PHPBB 3.0.10 and am having this error:

Strict Standards: Non-static method utf_normalizer::nfc() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPBB\includes\utf\utf_tools.php on line 1781

I have tried to find an answer for this on the PHPBB boards but have had no luck. I have a bit of background in PHP but don't understand static function calls from dynamic ones. I am using PHP v5.4.4, Apache 2.4.2 and Xampp 1.8.0, if any of that is of relevance. I am also running this on my localhost, not on a remote server.

To induce this error, all I am doing is installing PHPBB. Once I have inserted the Database settings and the Admin account settings, it comes up with this error and won't allow me to continue. I have no extensions installed (ofcourse).

Also, I have not been able to find the nfc function in the file specified. I am unsure as to whether it's in an include though. I also searched inside all files for "function nfc" (excluding quotation marks), but found nothing, and so am unable to use this: [Strict Standards: Non-static method STemplate::assign() should not be called statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721210/strict-standards-non-static-method-stemplateassign-should-not-be-called-sta)
. I am aware that this problem is common, and many people have claimed that a certain fix has worked for them, but I have been unable to apply these fixes because they were for earlier versions of PHPBB (i.e. 1.0.4).

I have been able to install PHPBB on localhost in the past, but not now. I currently have no working PHPBB installation.

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

go to your /includes folder and open up the startup.php

On line ~22 change the line

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

This may solve your problem =).

Comment: Thankyou, that worked and I have now been able to finish installing the forum.
However instead of hiding the error, do you know how I would go about fixing it?
Thanks.

Comment: Changing the error level does not fix the underlying error.  Why would you accept an answer that doesn't actually answer your question?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is outdated, however rather than suppressing the issue

If you want to properly fix this at the root of the problem,

Open up includes/utf/utf_tools.php

Go to ~line 1663

Replace

```
utf_normalizer::nfkc($text);
```

With

```
$utf_normalizer = new utf_normalizer();
$utf_normalizer->nfkc($text);
unset($utf_normalizer);
```

I'm still not sure why this hasn't been fixed in a proper release

Comment: This is also in the 3.0.12 release too! Using this line solves this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I run into a similar problem today after I updated to 3.0.12 and I think the proper solution is to make static all the functions in utf_normalizer.php instead of making non static all the calls to these functions.
BTW this is how it's done in phpbb 3.1.1